# How to change color of toolbar menu of collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to change default black color of collapsing toolbar menu.I read many answers but none of them could solve my problem.so please try to solve it.thank u.

[image]

Comment: Which default black do you mean? The image or the text, or is it the scrim (i.e. colour we can't until it starts collapsing)?

Comment: i think he's talking about the text coz the only black color i can see is there only @SaikCaskey

Comment: yes i want to change that text color